# yii2 transfering navbar widget parametres to single html parametres

Tags: php, yii2, frameworks

I was going to make yii2 popup window feedback form and I followed a programmers tutorial.  In the tutorial the programmer gave these parametres to navbar in main.php

```
echo Nav::widget([
        'options' => ['class' => 'navbar-nav navbar-right'],
        'items' => [
            ['label' => 'Home', 'url' => ['/site/index']],
            ['label' => 'About', 'url' => ['/site/about']],
            **['label' => 'Contact', 'url' => '#', 'options' => ['data-toggle' => 'modal', 'data-target' => '#myModal']]**,
```

the programmer gave these parametres inside nav widget which is in the contact label,

```
'options' => ['data-toggle' => 'modal', 'data-target' => '#myModal']
```

however, I must use -->['data-toggle' => 'modal', 'data-target' => '#myModal']<-- parametres in here :::

```
<a href="#" class="btn"><?=Yii::t('common', 'Participate'); ?></a>,
```

but i dont know how to give these values to my `<a> tag or here <?=Yii::t('common', 'Participate'); ?>,` 
what should I do and is there any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't you just use:

```
<a href="#" class="btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><?=Yii::t('common', 'Participate'); ?></a>
```

Comment: bro, i did it and it is not working, it was working in tihs position  ['label' => 'Contact', 'url' => '#', 'options' => ['data-toggle' => 'modal', 'data-target' => '#myModal'],